# Show on gridview data from two tables LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, webforms

i have two tables:
 1. Clients: clientID, Name, Surname, Address,
 2. Visit: visitID, clientID, Date, Place.
I want display on GridView list with visits details: Name,Surname,Address,Date,Place.

I have something like that but it not working correctly, it's only showing the data from Visit table:

```
using (NewEntities dc = new NewEntities())
            {
                var visits = (from a in dc.Visits
                              join b in dc.Clients on a.clientID equals b.clientID
                              select new 
                              {
                                  a,
                                  b.Name,b.Surname,b.Address,

                              });

                if (visits != null)
                {
                    allVisits = new List<Visits>();
                    foreach (var i in visits)
                    {
                            Visits c = i.a;

                        allVisits.Add(c);
                    }
                }

                if ((allVisits == null) || (allVisits.Count == 0))
                {
                    allVisits.Add(new Visits());
                    myGridView.DataSource = allVisits;
                    myGridView.DataBind();
                    myGridView.Rows[0].Visible = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    myGridView.DataSource = allVisits;
                    myGridView.DataBind();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I see on GridView only columns from one table Visits: visitID,clientID,Date,Place. I want display data from two tables.

Comment: You're binding the gridview to Visits, which only have visit info. You could bind the gridview to visits variable (from LINQ query) if that has the data you want to display.

Comment: Could you show me how it should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the visits variable, as it seems like that's the data you want.

```
using (NewEntities dc = new NewEntities())
{
    var visits = (from a in dc.Visits
              join b in dc.Clients on a.clientID equals b.clientID
              select new 
              {
                  a,
                  b.Name,b.Surname,b.Address,
              });

    myGridView.DataSource = visits.ToList();
    myGridView.DataBind();
}
```